# "shopping cart" list won't append within online shopping program, what am I missing?

Tags: python, list, append

My assignment involves building an online shopping program.  I have code that works, except that it won't append a *single* item to my shopping cart.  Nearly identical code works for appending *two* shirts.  Why won't it append for one?

Interestingly, it will not print the "Cart Updated" message I have after each append situation.

A lot of the following code is meeting the scenario/rules of the assignment; the append code is located in times the user wants to order 1 or 2 shirts.

```
cart = list()

def shop():
    # some code for shopping categories and displaying items
    pass

def shirtorder():
    while True:
        shirtitem = input('Please type in the name of the shirt you would like to purchase.''\n')
        numbershirt = input('How many would you like to purchase?''\n')
        numbershirt = int(numbershirt)
        if numbershirt > 2:
            print('We are sorry, but there are only 2', shirtitem, 'in stock.')
            while True:
                yesornoshirt = input('Would you like to order fewer of that shirt? Please answer "yes" or "no."''\n')
                if yesornoshirt == "yes" or yesornoshirt== "y" or yesornoshirt == "Y" or yesornoshirt == "Yes":
                    numbershirt = input('How many would you like to purchase?''\n')
                    numbershirt = int(numbershirt)
                    if numbershirt == 2:
                        while len(cart) >= 0:
                            cart.append(shirtitem)
                            cart.append(shirtitem)
                            print('Cart updated.')
                            shop()
                            break
                        break
                    if numbershirt == 1:
                        while len(cart) >= 0:
                            cart.append(shirtitem)
                            print('Cart updated.')
                            shop()
                            break
                        break
                    if numbershirt == 0:
                        shop()
                        break
                    if numbershirt < 0:
                        print('Invalid number of shirts. Please try again.')
                        continue
                if yesornoshirt == "n" or yesornoshirt == "no" or yesornoshirt == "No" or yesornoshirt == "N":
                    print('None have been added to your cart.')
                    shop()
                    break
                try:
                    yesornoshirt = float(yesornoshirt)
                    yesornoshirt = int(yesornoshirt)
                except:
                    print('Please answer only "yes" or "no."')
                    continue
        if numbershirt == 2:
            while len(cart) >= 0:
                cart.append(shirtitem)
                cart.append(shirtitem)
                print('Cart updated.')
                shop()
                break
            break
        break
        if numbershirt == 1:
            while len(cart) >= 0:
                cart.append(shirtitem)
                print('Cart updated.')
                shop()
                break
            break
        break
        if numbershirt == 0:
            shop()
            break
        if numbershirt < 0:
            print('Invalid number of shirts. Please try again.')
            continue

shirtorder()

print(cart)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce *only* the problem you described.

Comment: I’m completely new to all of this, so thanks for the tip on posting!

Answer (score 1):

**IMMEDIATE PROBLEM**

Your logic flow is faulty:

```
if numbershirt == 2:
    while len(cart) >= 0:
        cart.append(shirtitem)
        cart.append(shirtitem)
        print('Cart updated. 2Y')
        shop()
        break  # problem 3
    break  # problem 2
break  # problem 1

if numbershirt == 1:
    print ("TRACE A1: cart", cart, len(cart))
    while len(cart) >= 0:
        ...
```

*problem 1*: Do you know what **break** does?  In this case, it exits the **while** loop.  You can never reach the following statement, so there's no way to register a single shirt -- or no shirts, or negative shirts.

*problem 2*: What do you expect this to do?  You're breaking out of an **if** statement, which is not an iterative process.

*problem 3*: This *must* exit your **while** on the first execution, which says that you shouldn't be using a **while** at all.

**ANALYSIS**

Very briefly, you tried to program far beyond your capabilities in one sitting.  You've written over 70 lines of code without testing the pieces; you now have several mistakes in multiple places.  You're not comfortable with writing some combinations of control flow ... *yet*.

Fortunately, that's fixable.  Welcome to the learning process.

**WHAT TO DO**

Use incremental programming.  Write a few lines of code.  Test them, fix them, and keep testing until you're sure those lines are solid.  *Then* add a few more lines.  This will keep you from reusing code with errors in it.

For instance, start with a *forced* case of a particular shirt.  Something like this (using your current set-up):

```
shirtitem = "Generic white tee"
numbershirt = 2
if numbershirt == 2
    cart.append(shirtitem)
    cart.append(shirtitem)
    print('Cart updated;', numbershirt, shirtitem)
    print('Cart:', cart)
```

Notice the simple changes: tracing output to show the results; I removed the useless **while**.

Now, what would this look like if you could take up to 10 shirts?  Can you make it general enough to handle any quantity?  You'll need a loop for the **append** operations.

*Now* you're ready to try user input.  Don't repeat yet: the shopper gets one choice of shirt and quantity; then you kick them out of the store, because your trainee's brain is full.

Once *that* works well, you can loop for more shirts.  This program works pretty well constructing from the inside out.  Have fun.  Write lots of **print** statements; comment them out when you don't need them, but don't delete them until the whole program is working for, say, a week.

Comment: Thank you for the insights! I am totally beyond my capabilities after basic introductory work and now, what seems in comparison, a complicated project, at least to me a beginner. I tried what you said and copied my code into a second editor to test piece by piece. That really helped. I was breaking the assignment into pieces but will now go a step farther and break down and test even more. :)  I appreciate your time to help with the code and give me a strategy to use moving forward immensely!